# Copy all the contents of a directory and create a zip file

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been trying to write a small application using wxwidgets(C++) that copies all the contents of the temp directory of an application and zip all the contents of the directory. I however am not able to copy the contents of the temp area completely.
Here is my code

```
 wxString result;
 result = wxFileName::GetTempDir(); //Gets the temp area.

 wxFileName dir(result, wxEmptyString);
 dir.AppendDir(_T("Application"));
 bool a = dir.DirExists();
 wxFFileOutputStream out(_T("test.zip"));
 wxZipOutputStream zip(out);
 wxString sep(wxFileName::GetPathSeparator());

 zip.PutNextEntry(_T("entry1.txt"));
 wxString temp = dir.GetLongPath();
 zip.PutNextDirEntry(temp);
```

I am able to create test.zip and write entry1.txt and also the temp directory( without its contents). However, I dont seem to understand how to copy the subdirectories and the files in the directory.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is the zip file probably created in that temp directory?

Comment: so the actual question is how to iterate recursively through all the files and subfolders or a particular folder? that depends on the operating system.

Comment: @MariusBancila Not recursively iterate through all files and subfolders of a particular folder, but just to copy all the contents of the directory completely without iterating through the directory and not individually copy the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [wxDir](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dir.html) to enumerate the files and subdirectories of the given directory. Use [wxDirTraverser](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dir_traverser.html) or `wxDir::GetAllFiles()` to do the same thing recursively.